# Why Bootstrap Navbar not collapsing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty much using the exact W3schools example for collapsing `navbars`, and it isn't working. I'm sure I'm overlooking something but can't seem to pin point it. Attached is my HTML code. Cheers!

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" >
     openTab("Home")

  function openTab(tabName) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
        </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"  onclick="openTab('Home')">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="openTab('About')">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="openTab('Products')">Products</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#" onclick="openTab('Contact')">Contact Us</a></li> 
          </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: The HTML here is only 1/3 of the story. Can you make a CodePen with the needed JavaScript and CSS, as well?

Comment: I've added the bit of JavaScript that I'm using to hide all other divs when a tab is clicked, i.e. clicking on 'About' hides all divs except the 'About' one. As for CSS, it is just the base bootstrap styling have not modified it at all.

Comment: Hi @PS97, you should include your JS in the same snippet.

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani Sorry didn't know how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet that you have provided is correct. The main reason behind the issue will be the missing of bootstrap or jQuery files. Please include the below lines and please run again the code.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I could of sworn I properly linked bootstrap... feel so silly haha greatly appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Cool go ahead:)

Answer (score 1):

include this 4 lines to your head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The meta line of code fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should include proper `<head>` tag. The following code should work fine:

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
        </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"  onclick="openTab('Home')">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="openTab('About')">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="openTab('Products')">Products</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#" onclick="openTab('Contact')">Contact Us</a></li> 
          </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy, paste and replace your content It's working fine. Most probably you are missing bootstrap files.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
         <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
      </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="myNavbar">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li><a href="#"  onclick="openTab('Home')">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" onclick="openTab('About')">About Us</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" onclick="openTab('Products')">Products</a></li> 
           <li><a href="#" onclick="openTab('Contact')">Contact Us</a></li> 
         </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cheers aavrug all sorted :)